# Simplifying the use of std::function stored within a class's std::vector member

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, std-function, stdbind

I have written this basic class to store `std::function<T>` within `std::vector<T>` and I have two free function templates `foo()` and `bar()` that both return `void` and take a `std::vector<T>` as their parameter. Currently they do exactly the same for simplicity sakes; but let's say for future reference they will be doing different calculations or tasks.  So far this is what I have come up with:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

template<typename T>
class MyClass {
private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(std::vector<T>)>> myFuncs_;    
public:
    MyClass() = default;

    void addFunc( std::function<void(std::vector<T>)> func ) {
        myFuncs_.push_back(func);
    }

    std::function<void(std::vector<T>)> caller(unsigned idx) {
        return myFuncs_.at(idx);
    }
};

template<typename T>
void foo(std::vector<T> data) {
    std::cout << "foo() called:\n";

    for (auto& d : data) 
        std::cout << d << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template<typename T>
void bar(std::vector<T> data) {
    std::cout << "bar() called:\n";

    for (auto& d : data)
        std::cout << d << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
} 

int main() {
    try {
        MyClass<int> myClass;
        std::vector<int> a{ 1,3,5,7,9 };
        std::vector<int> b{ 2,4,6,8,10 };

        std::function<void(std::vector<int>)> funcA = std::bind(foo<int>, a);
        std::function<void(std::vector<int>)> funcB = std::bind(bar<int>, b);
        myClass.addFunc( funcA );
        myClass.addFunc( funcB );

        myClass.caller(0)(a);
        myClass.caller(1)(b);       

    } catch( std::runtime_error& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}
```

And this sure enough outputs:

```
foo() called:
1 3 5 7 9
bar() called:
2 4 6 8 10
```

---

Here's what I would like to know: is there or are there any way(s) to simplify this code; some of the syntax looks redundant, for example: In the main function after I had instantiated an instance of my class template and created an `std::vector` with values, I then create an instance of `std::function<T>` using `std::bind` with the function I want to then add to my class's vector. Then after binding them and adding them to my class's container, this is where I call the class's function to index the function I want to  call using `std::functions`'s `operator()`. However the function is expecting a `std::vector<T>` so it appears that I am passing this `vector<T>` multiple times as you can see from this part from my code above.

```
// std::vector<T> being passed to std::bind
std::function<void(std::vector<int>)> funcA = std::bind(foo<int>,a);
myClass.addFunc( funcA );
myClass.caller(0)(a);  // Again std::vector<T> being passed but to `std::function`'s operator because the stored function requires this parameter.
```

Can this be simplified or is this just in the semantics of how `std::function` and `std::bind` work? If this can be simplified, would it be done within the class itself to make it easier on the user or would it be from the user side?

Comment: Using compiler type deduction with `auto` is a good start to simplify things. As is using type-aliases in the class for commonly used types (like the `std::function` type).

Comment: And instead of a getter function that returns the function, perhaps have a "call" function instead (or perhaps even a call operator)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was thinking on those lines, but I'm not real efficient with using `std::function` nor `std::bind` yet and the syntax is cluttering my thinking process; haha.... Then again it is a bit late, I might take a break from it and work on it tomorrow.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude an example of `type-aliases` and a `call` function would be appreciated.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Instead of `std::bind()` you should use capturing lambda functions.

Comment: You don't need `bind` here: `foo<int>` already has appropriate type... It gets more obvious if you use a lambda instead; this is equivalent to what `bind` would have produced: `funcA = [&]() { foo<int>(a); }` - notice the mismatching signature...

Comment: @Aconcagua I tried a lambda; but I think that's one thing I was missing, the `reference` in the capture clause.

Comment: @FrancisCugler But you don't need it, neither bind nor lambda: Just have: `std::function<void(std::vector<int>) f = foo<int>;`: `f` want's something returning void and accepting vector, `foo` does so.

Comment: @Aconcagua hmm MSVC is giving me problems with trying to assign the lambda to an `std::function`...

Comment: @FrancisCugler Because of mismatching type, see previous comments...

Comment: @Aconcagua I think that's what I was missing. After changing it to `... = foo<int>;`  & `... = bar<int>;` I think I'm starting to understand `std::function` a little better. I'm declaring `funcA` and `funcB` as an `std::function<T>` but when assigning them you can assign to them the address of a function; thus a `pointer to a function`.

Comment: @FrancisCugler ... or a lambda or a functor object - as long as the signature is matching (lambda)/an appropriate `operator()` is provided (functor). `std::function` is a multi-purpose container.

Comment: @Aconcagua Actually MSVC is not wrong here, because `std::bind`ed function will ignore any redundant arguments, instead of a compile error. That's expected. @FrancisCugler Your code is not working, it works just by chance. The `a` in `myClass.caller(0)(a);` has no effect at all. You can try replacing it with `myClass.caller(0)(b);`, the output should be exactly the same.

Comment: @liliscent Here I thought that `.caller(0)` would give the index to the `vector` by using it's `at()` function, and then since this is retrieving a `std::function` that is stored at index `0` or `1`, that using `(a)` or `(b)` after it would then be using `std::function`'s `operator()` allowing you to `call` the function pointer as well as pass to it its needed parameter(s)... Or am I missing something?

Comment: @FrancisCugler You have some serious misunderstanding on `std::bind`, it's not easy to explain because I dont know why you misunderstood it in that way. I suggest you read the *examples* in the docs carefully. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

Comment: @FrancisCugler Trying again with lambda: `[&](std::vector<int> other) { foo<int>(a); }` The important thing about is: `bind(foo<int>, a)` makes call `foo` with `a` instead of `other`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `std::bind` the wrong way, e.g in

```
std::function<void(std::vector<int>)> funcA = std::bind(foo<int>, a);
```

You've already bound the argument `a` to `foo<int>` which mean that whatever parameter you'll pass to `funcA` will not take effect, the above is equivalent to

```
std::function<void()> funcA = std::bind(foo<int>, a);
```

For the part of code simplicity, if you want to stick with `std::bind` you can just have a call operator on `MyClass` that call all the registered `std::function`:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
private:
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> myFuncs_;
public:
    MyClass() = default;

    template <class... F, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(F) > 0), bool> = true>
    void addFunc(F&&... func) {
        ((myFuncs_.push_back(std::forward<F>(func))), ...);
    }

    void operator()() const {
        for (auto& fn : myFuncs_) {
            fn();
        }
    }
};


auto funcA = std::bind(foo<int>, a);
auto funcB = std::bind(bar<int>, b);
myClass.addFunc(funcA, funcB);
myClass();
```

using this same idea you can at any time switch to lambdas instead.